# Modify a key-value in a json using jq in-place

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a json in which I want to modify a particular value but the terminal always displays the json with the modified value but it does not actually change the value in the particular file.

Sample json:

```json
{
    "name": "abcd",
    "age": 30,
    "address": "abc"
}
```

I want to change the value of address in the file itself but so far I've been unable to do so. I tried using:

```
jq '.address = "abcde"' test.json
```

but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jq to replace text directly on file (like sed -i)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565295/jq-to-replace-text-directly-on-file-like-sed-i)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

AFAIK `jq` does not support in-place editing, so you must redirect to a temporary file first and then replace your original file with it, or use `sponge` utility from the moreutils package, like that:

```
jq '.address = "abcde"' test.json|sponge test.json
```

There are other techniques to "redirect to the same file", like saving your output in a variable e.t.c. "Unix & Linux StackExchange" is a good place to start, if you want to learn more about this.

Comment: Unfortunately moreutils / sponge is unavailable on CentOS 8 atm..

Comment: Without `sponge`: `echo "$( jq '.address = "abcde"' test.json )" > test.json`

Comment: Be careful! Pass the filename as an argument to `sponge`, as in the answer. This is wrong: `jq . test.json | sponge > test.json` , you must do `jq . test.json | sponge test.json`

Comment: An additional nod for getting me to look at sponge(1)

Comment: do not redirect to the same file as suggested by @codekandis comment. this will not always work. Large files it will cause issues, also with whitespaces, non-printable and escapment sequences. Never redirect a file to itself, it is always a bad idea. See sponge or use a temp file, just don't try to do it differently unless you understand what is happening.

Answer (score 163):

Use a temporary file; it's what any program that claims to do in-place editing is doing.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
jq '.address = "abcde"' test.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" test.json
```

If the address isn't hard-coded, pass the correct address via a `jq` argument:

```
address=abcde
jq --arg a "$address" '.address = $a' test.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" test.json
```

Comment: this worked for a hardcoded string. Is there any solution for a variable i.e $address

Comment: @ahmed_khan_89 you can use jq '.address = "'${address}'"'

Comment: No, do not interpolate strings into a `jq` filter. Use `jq --arg a "$address" '.address = $a'` instead.

Comment: @chepner How come you don't recommend interpolating the string? It works when I use Pujan's method

Comment: It's an enormous headache to deal with the quoting. Use --arg

Comment: @AlexanderD Because interpolation doesn't necessarily pass an argument to your filter; it *builds* a filter, and that filter depends on how the variable expansion is parsed.

Comment: Notice the file owner and file permission of the `test.json` will be altered due to use of `mv`. I usually use `cat` instead.

Comment: `mv` is atomic; `cat` is not. You can adjust the permissions and owner of the temp file before executing `mv`, but preventing another process from accessing `test.json` while `cat` overwrites its contents is more difficult.

Comment: another common temp filename is adding a tilde like `test.json~`, or prepending a dot and something more, like `.jq.test.json`, keeping the file in the same directory. this way, the move operation doesn't potentially cross filesystems which would result in a non-atomic copy&delete operation. plus: mktemp sets its own permissions. might be wanted, but might not

Answer (score 75):

Temp files add more complexity when not needed (unless you are truly dealing with JSON files so large you cannot fit them in memory (GB to 100's of GB or TB, depending on how much RAM/parallelism you have)

The Pure bash way.

```
contents="$(jq '.address = "abcde"' test.json)" && \
echo -E "${contents}" > test.json
```

### Pros

- No temp file to juggle
- Pure bash
- Don't need an admin to install `sponge`, which is not installed by default
- Simpler

### Cons

- This works perfectly fine for json because it cannot contain a literal null character. If you were to try this outside the json arena, it would fail when a null is encountered (and you would have to do some encoding/decoding workarounds). Bash variables cannot store literal nulls.

**Note**: this can not be combined as "one command" (like @codekandis
suggested), since redirection sometimes starts *before* the left hand side (LHS) of an expression is run, and starting redirection before running `jq` erroneously empties the file, hence two separate commands. It may "seem" to work when you try it, but this is misleading and has a very high probability of failing as soon as the circumstances change.

*Update*: Added `-E` option to disable escape characters *just in case* you are on `systems where they are interpreted by default.` (Which I've never actually seen)

Comment: This answer is particularly useful for things such as bumping the version on your package.json (e.g. `contents="$(jq '.version = "$version"' package.json)" && echo "${contents}" > package.json`)

Comment: This shorter version seems to work: `echo -E $(jq '.address = "abcde"' test.json) > test.json`

Comment: @Pieter you should not do that. It is extremely unreliable and will fail once the circumstances change (file size, formatted file system, CPU usage, phase of the moon). As soon the redirection on the RHS opens and clears the `test.json` file the `jq` running is now reading file contents that are most likely missing. It mat seem to work, but this is not safe.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I also noticed that it prints everything in one line, so it doesn't even work.

Comment: @Pieter The reason why everything was one line was because you didn't put quotes around the $() expression. You lose **all** preservation of whitespaces when you do that in bash. You technically don't need the quotes in the `contents=` example, because those quote are implicit. But notice I do have quotes in the echo command, that is important, or else all multiple spaces/tabs/newlines are replaced with single spaces. If we want compact output, use `jq -c`

Comment: I think `contents` variable also needed to be unset to prevent memory leaks if the script runs forever.

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to chepner answer and if you want it in a shell script.

test.json

```
{
  "name": "abcd",
  "age": 30,
  "address": "abc"
}
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
address="abcde"
age=40

# Strings:
jq --arg a "${address}" '.address = $a' test.json > "tmp" && mv "tmp" test.json

# Integers:
jq --argjson a "${age}" '.age = $a' test.json > "tmp" && mv "tmp" test.json
```

Answer (score 8):

Example for nested json with changing single and multiple values.

config.json

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "Environment": "Prod",
    "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
    "AMIID": "ami-02d8e11",
    "ConfigRegion": "eu-west-1"
  }
}
```

with the below command, you can edit multiple values.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
jq '.Parameters.AMIID = "ami-02d8sdfsdf" | .Parameters.Environment = "QA"' config.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" config.json
```

with the below command, you can edit single value.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
jq '.Parameters.AMIID = "ami-02d8sdfsdf"' config.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" config.json
```

Answer (score 7):

this should work

```
address = aaaaa
echo $(jq --arg a "$address" '.address = ($a)' test.json) > test.json
```

for whatever reason, without the echo, it makes a bin file and my python script was not able to parse it.

Comment: Streaming the result into the input file is generally risky in shell scripts: `>` normally causes the output file to be truncated before the rest of the command is executed. Possibly the subshell command `$(...)` postpones this until after the execution of the shell script. In general I would always use a command line option to deal with this special case, or lacking that, write to an intermediate file.

Answer (score 2):

I took the best of a couple answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61049639/901899) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69196044/901899).

This uses a parameter named `actionname` as an input to an assignment of the `name` property at the document level. ACTION_NAME is just an envvar I want to use as the replacement value.

```bash
contents="$(jq --arg actionname ${ACTION_NAME} '.name = $actionname' ./${ACTION_NAME}/package.json)" && \
echo -E "${contents}" > ${ACTION_NAME}/package.json;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is just to store interim JSON to a variable rather than a file.

```bash
JSON=$(jq '.address = "abcde"' test.json)
echo "$JSON" > test.json
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't like any of the solutions and created the [`sde` utility](https://github.com/dvershinin/sde).

```bash
pip install sde
```

Then, e.g. for the following JSON data:

```json
{
  "Parameters": {
    "Environment": "Prod",
    "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
    "AMIID": "ami-02d8e11",
    "ConfigRegion": "eu-west-1"
  }   
}
```

you can simply do:

```bash
sde Parameters.Environment Dev test.json
```