# Find and replace text in JSON with sed

Tags: json, bash, sed

An example of the JSON is something like

```
{"version":"0.5363"}
```

I'd need to be able to inject a new value for version thorugh a variable. I found one solution on stackoverflow which says:

```
echo '{"version":"0.5363"}' | sed 's/\({"version":"\)[^"]*\("}\)/\1newvalue\2/g'
```

But i wanted to replace the newvalue through varable i.e

```
echo '{"version":"0.5363"}' | sed 's/\({"version":"\)[^"]*\("}\)/\1$newvalue\2/g'
```

But is is replacing the string as

```
{"version":"$newvalue"}
```

The above example is refrenced one. Actually my JSON looks like below:
"checksum": "sdkjjfj-shbdjfj23"

I wanted to replace the checksum value with another value.
As per above I used :
sed -i 's/("checksum": ")[^"]*(")/\1$checksumVal\2/g' new.json

The new.json is updated as below, but i wanted the value of that variable.
"checksum": "$checksumVal",

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: JSON with `sed` is incorrect and not recommended, use `jq` and format your code with 4 spaces

Comment: For posterity, a solution using `jq` - [Modify a key-value in a json using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42716734/5291015)

Comment: and `jq '.version = "'"$newvalue"'"'` for using variable.. add `-c` option to get compact output