# Find and replace text in JSON with sed using shell variables

Tags: json, bash, sed

Actually my JSON looks like below:

> "checksum": "sdkjjfj-shbdjfj23"

I wanted to replace the checksum value with another value. As per above I used :

> sed -i 's/("checksum": ")[^"]*(")/\1$checksumVal\2/g' new.json

The new.json is updated as below, but i wanted the value of that variable.

> "checksum": "$checksumVal",

Expected Result:

> "checksum": "newval"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you were given two different suggestions for this in previous question you asked(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813321/find-and-replace-text-in-json-with-sed) ... did you try them?

Comment: Yes, I tried all the given options but no luck. sed -i 's/("checksum": ")[^"]*(")/\1 "'"$checksumVal"'"'\2/g' new.json This command is also not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use one `echo` statement and check whether `$checksumVal` has some value or not and also try like below it work for me. How will it work
`sed "/checksum` will search for pattern `"checksum` once it found the pattern it will search for pattern `: "*"` (with wild card) in this example it is `: "sdkjjfj-shbdjfj23"` and this pattern will be replace with `: "$checksumVal"`

```
 sed "/checksum/s/: ".*"/: \"$checksumVal\"/" new.json
```

Comment: Yes, I am getting the output after doing >echo $checksumVal         
 sed -i 's/("checksum": ")[^"]*(")/\1"$checksumVal"\2/g' new.json
Error: sed: -e expression #1, char 46: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS                                                                                             First 3 options are not working for me. There are removing the linw which containes checksum word nothing else.

Comment: @sush, I have modified my answer. Try with this and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `jq`?:

```
$ cat foo.json # added the required {}
{"checksum": "sdkjjfj-shbdjfj23"}
$ echo $checksum
foo
$ jq '.checksum = "'"$checksum"'"' foo.json
{
  "checksum": "foo"
}
```

Comment: Yes, It is working fine if I create the new json file which contains only checksum field. But my original new.json file containes multiple json fields, there this commad is not working. It is giving following error:                  
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 3, column 15.                          At line 3 there are { characters.

Comment: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 3, column 15 Is this error is relevant with jq?

Comment: Yes, it is always a problem when the question posters do not provide adequate sample data. The solutions are therefore left untested against realistic data.