# How to modify multiple json files

Tags: python, json

I have a folder with 100 json files and I have to add `[` at the beginning  and `]` at the end of each file .

The file structure is:

```
{
item
}
```

However, I need to transform all of them like so:

```
[{
item
}]
```

How to do that?

Comment: `json.dump([json.load(infile)], outfile)`.

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -i '1s/^/[/; $s/$/]/' file.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would normally recommend using `json.load` and `json.dump` for anything related to JSON, due to your specific requirements the following scrip should suffice:

```py
import os

os.chdir('path to your directory')

for fp in os.listdir('.'):
    if fp.endswith('.json'):
        f = open(fp, 'r+')
        content = f.read()
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        f.write('[' + content + ']')
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use glob module to parse through all the files. then you can read the contents and then modify that content and write back to the file

```
from glob import glob

for filename in glob('./json/*.json'):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    contents = f.read()
    f.close()
    new_contents = f"[{contents}]"
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    f.write(new_contents)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
for fn in glob.glob('/path/*'):
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    with open(fn, 'w') as f:
        f.write('[' + data + ']')
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

```sh
# One file

$ jq '.=[.]' test.json | sponge test.json

# Many files

find . -type f -name '*.json' -exec sh -c "jq '.=[.]' "{}" | sponge "{}"" \;
```

## Breakdown

Let's take a sample file

```sh
$ cat test.json
```

```json
{
    "hello":"world"
}
```

```sh
$ jq '.=[.]' test.json
```

Above, the dot (.) represents the root node. So I'm taking the root node and putting it inside brackets. So we get:

```json
[
  {
    "hello": "world"
  }
]
```

Now we need to take the output and put it back into the file

```
$ jq '.=[.]' test.json | sponge test.json
$ cat test.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "hello": "world"
  }
]
```

Next, let's find all the json files where we want to do this

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.json' 
./test.json
```

We can iterate over each line of the find command and cat it as as follow:

```sh
$ find . -type f -name '*.json' -exec cat {}\;
{
    "hello":"world"
}
```

or instead we can compose the jq command that we need. The filename is passed to the curly braces between `-exec` and `\;`

```sh
$ find . -type f -name '*.json' -exec sh -c "jq '.=[.]' "{}" | sponge "{}"" \;
```

- [jq](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/jq/jq.1.en.html)
- [sponge](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/sponge.1.html)

Thanks to [zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42717073/1643061)