# How to replace Image with jq in Kubernetes Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, jq

How can I replace the Image used in a Kubernetes Deployment manifest with jq?

For example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myapp-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myapp:v1
```

I tried using something like this `jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image = "myapp:v2"'`. However, it always ends with a syntax or parse error.

Comment: JQ is for parsing JSON. You are looking for YQ

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716734/modify-a-key-value-in-a-json-using-jq-in-place  suggests otherwise

Comment: As @ogus ismael suggests: jq can not parse yaml. If you really want to use jq you would need to convert yaml to json, e.g. with https://github.com/wakeful/yaml2json - and convert it back afterwards e.g. with https://github.com/brancz/gojsontoyaml. But I wouldn’t recommend to be honest.

Comment: Kubernetes-native tools like Helm or Kustomize might also be able to help with this particular case.

Comment: Got  a bit confused and thought that yaml is valid json

Comment: @Pascal Backwards. YAML is a proper superset of JSON, so JSON is valid YAML, but not all YAML is valid JSON. What you posted is not valid [JSON](https://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), you can simply write:

```
yq -y '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image = "foo:latest"' pod.yml
```

Which produces:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myapp-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: foo:latest
```

But I would use [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) for something like this, as @DavidMaze suggested.