# Change a value in a json file using zsh

Tags: javascript, json, zsh

I have a JSON file, I'm trying to change a particular value in it using a script.

```json
"foo-bar": "baz",
```

It is set as baz in this example, but in practice I don't know what this value is.

I want to change `foo-bar`'s value from within a larger script.

```json
"foo-bar": "qux",
```

I tried

```
$var='qux'
jq --arg passvar ${var} '{"foo-bar":$passvar}' file.json
```

I get the correct output in terminal

```
{
"foo-bar": "qux"
}
```

But when I check the actual file contents using vim, I get

```json
"foo-bar": "baz",
```

`jq` doesn't want to save the new file.json? Or is that a preview of some sort?
What am I missing? Is there a better way than `jq` to update/set values in a json file?

*edited to add a dash to the initial variable, it is now foo-bar instead of just foo.

Comment: see: [Jq to replace text directly on file (like sed -i)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565295/jq-to-replace-text-directly-on-file-like-sed-i)

Comment: Your attempt *ignores* `file.json` and outputs the object created by your filter.

Comment: `jq` can only read from a file and write to standard output; it has no facilities for writing to any other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True answer is here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42718624/1286903

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
jq --arg p "$p" '."foo-bar" = $p' file.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file.json
```

`'."foo-bar"` is the key you want to edit.

You need to make use of a temp file to do this. Also, be mindful of quotes when your vars have dashes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> The output(s) of the filter are written to standard out

So, you need to redirect the output to whatever file you want.

```
jq --arg passvar ${var} '{"foo":$passvar}' file.json > newfile.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indeed, and if you want to pass it to the same file, `file.json`, you need to pass it to a temp file `tmp.json` then back to `file.json`.