# How to Iterate Json key value pair and get the value and store in another json using Bash Script with JQ utility

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, jq

Im writing bash script for AWS Secret Manager .

Question:

I have one aws secret manager it will contain multiple secret

Example:
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id Example | jq -r ".SecretString"

input.json

```
{"Username":"admin","Password":"admin","Endpoint":"localhost","DatabaseName":"example","Port":"3306"}
```

Using this command got a json output

Now I want to extract All values like (Username , password,..)

After get all extract values add in another json file called (secondfile.json)

I have another json file it will contain

this is secondfile.json

```
 {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Aurora": {
    "Username": "",
    "Password": "",
    "Endpoint": "",
    "DatabaseName": "",
    "Port": ""
  }
}
```

Sample Output: extracted values now stored second file.json file in Aurora[] array elements.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Aurora": {
    "Username": "admin",
    "Password": "admin",
    "Endpoint": "localhost",
    "DatabaseName": "example",
    "Port": "3306"
  }
}
```

Need Help on do with bash script .

**Note: Input.json value not fixed , it may be contain 3 json key/value or n number of key/value**

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716734/modify-a-key-value-in-a-json-using-jq-in-place

Comment: But output should be stored in another json value with correct key and value

Comment: I understand. You have to pick these values first, then create a temporary file where You store them and lastly You move them into the desired file. Jq can not write to th file. You have to use the shell commands.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question. What is your goal and the final output? What for do you need the output?

Comment: Can you help me through any examples

Comment: Hi @knittl I have input.json file and get all the value and store in to output,.json file

Comment: {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Aurora": {
    "Username": "admin",
    "Password": "admin",
    "Endpoint": "localhost",
    "DatabaseName": "example",
    "Port": "3306"
  }
}  This is the exact output

Comment: What should happen when keys are missing from the input or from the expected output? e.g. `secondfile.json` contains a key "Environment", but the `input.json` file does not? Similarly, what should happen with keys in `input.json` that are not listed in `secondfile.json`? You only specified _that_ it can happen, but not _what_ should happen in that case. What would the expected output be?

Comment: Is `input.json` created from the _output_ of the `aws` command?

Comment: @glennjackman yes i have created json from that command , which ever value i have got need to add in secondfile.json file

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want to embed/wrap the input document in a top level document.

```
echo '{"Username":"admin","Password":"admin","Endpoint":"localhost","DatabaseName":"example","Port":"3306"}' | jq '{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Aurora": .
}'
```

Output:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Aurora": {
    "Username": "admin",
    "Password": "admin",
    "Endpoint": "localhost",
    "DatabaseName": "example",
    "Port": "3306"
  }
}
```

The key "Aurora" will contain your input document. If you need only specific fields, then replace `.` with `{Username,Password}`

Comment: Hi @knittl . Im not just echo and embedded the value , Input json file iterate  and get all value and store in to output.json file in aurora json value should be in dynamic in nature

Comment: @Muthu I don't understand. If you have an input file redirect with `<input.json` (or use `cat input.json | …`) It is still unclear what you are trying to achieve. What does "iterate" mean? Edit your question to include the input and the expected output. Right now, this answer matches your input (the echo part) and your output.

Comment: Please check now let me know if you are able to unserstand

Comment: Please let me know if you are able to understand

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution how to jq's `--slurpfile` option to use another file as "template" to format your input and then replace the parts according to your requirements:

```
$ cat template.json
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "Aurora": {
        "Username": "",
        "Password": "",
        "Endpoint": "",
        "DatabaseName": "",
        "Port": "",
        "Environment": ""
    }
}

$ cat input.json
{
  "Username": "admin",
  "Password": "admin",
  "Endpoint": "localhost",
  "DatabaseName": "example",
  "Port": "3306",
  "SomethingElse": "ignore me"
}

$ jq --slurpfile tpl template.json '$tpl[0] + {Aurora: with_entries(select(.key | IN($tpl[0].Aurora|keys[])))}' <input.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Aurora": {
    "Username": "admin",
    "Password": "admin",
    "Endpoint": "localhost",
    "DatabaseName": "example",
    "Port": "3306"
  }
}
```

Or swapping template and input files:

```
$ jq --slurpfile in input.json '.Aurora |= keys as $keys | $in[0] | with_entries(select(.key | IN($keys[])))' <template.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Aurora": {
    "Username": "admin",
    "Password": "admin",
    "Endpoint": "localhost",
    "DatabaseName": "example",
    "Port": "3306"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your "template" file, I would suggest not keeping it as JSON, but make it a jq program instead:

```
$ cat input.json
{
  "Username": "admin",
  "Password": "admin",
  "Endpoint": "localhost",
  "DatabaseName": "example",
  "Port": "3306",
  "SomethingElse": "ignore me"
}

$ cat filter.jq
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "Aurora": {
        "Username": .Username,
        "Password": .Password,
        "Endpoint": .Endpoint,
        "DatabaseName": .DatabaseName,
        "Port": .Port
    }
}

$ jq -f filter.jq < input.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Aurora": {
    "Username": "admin",
    "Password": "admin",
    "Endpoint": "localhost",
    "DatabaseName": "example",
    "Port": "3306"
  }
}
```

Note that the filter program can be written with shorthand syntax:

```
$ cat filter.jq
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "Aurora": {
        Username,
        Password,
        Endpoint,
        DatabaseName,
        Port
    }
}
```