# Change JSON field value in Dockerfile

Tags: json, dockerfile, jq

I have a "config.json" file that i use inside a Dockerfile to set some specific parameter.

I need to replace the value of a field of this file with a random string.
Suppose the file structure is something like the code shown below and the field value to replace is the one of "field_2"

```
{ 
  ...
  "things":[{
    "field_1":"val_1",
    "field_2":"val_2"
   }],
   ...
}
```

I've tryed with "jq" but it didn't seem to work, I'll provide my code below:

```
# Copy File
COPY /config.json /app/config.json

# Install jq
RUN apk add jq

# Use jq to update the value in config.json
RUN jq '.things[0].field_2= "$(openssl rand -base64 12)"' /app/config.json > /app/new_config.json 
RUN mv /app/new_config.json /app/config.json
```

Could you please help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Fabio

Comment: The Docker context is an unnecessary complication. `jq` doesn't support shell command substitutions as part of the script, but if you are using a Unix shell, you can say `jq --arg rand "$(openssl rand -base64 12)" '.things[0].field_2=$rand'`. (Also, your example JSON is invalid.)

Comment: Tangentially, repeatedly copying the input file to different places is pretty redundant. Just `copy` the temporary file to a temporary location and use that as input to `jq`, then delete when you have generated the production file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Processing command substitutions in strings embedded in a .json file with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68647601/processing-command-substitutions-in-strings-embedded-in-a-json-file-with-jq)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is with a POSIX shell and a variable:

```
jq --arg rand "$(openssl rand -base64 12)" '.things[0].field_2 = $rand'
```

Your original code did not work because single quotes prevent command substitution.