# How to change json object using jq bash

Tags: linux, bash, jq

I have a `json` object that looks like below:

```
{
    "CallerReference": "terraform-20210518124856158900000001",
    "Aliases": {
        "Quantity": 3,
        "Items": [
            "consumer-portal.mlb.effi.com.au",
            "*.mlb.effi.com.au",
            "coolvalue.mylocalbroker.com.au"
        ]
    }
}
```

And I need to;

1. First get the value of `Quantity`
2. Increment it by 1
3. Then change that value so it looks like `"Quantity": 4,`
4. And I need to add another entry at the bottom of the `Items` array.

I am using `jq` and trying to first replace the `"Quantity"` value as below:

```
filename=cf.json
rm $filename
aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id <ID> \
  --query 'DistributionConfig' --output json > $filename

etag=$(aws cloudfront  get-distribution-config --id <ID> |
       jq -r '.ETag')

aws cloudfront update-distribution \
  --distribution-config file://$filename --id <ID> --if-match $etag > /dev/null

jq --argjson i "10" '.Aliases.Quantity[$i]' $filename
```

But I am getting this error:

> jq: error (at cf.json:136): Cannot index number with number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like `+=` should to the trick <sup>[[docs]](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example97)</sup>

- `.Aliases.Quantity += 1` To increment `Quantity` by `1`
- `.Aliases.Items += [ "Example" ]` To add a new index to the `Items` array

Full command:

```
jq '.Aliases.Quantity += 1 | .Aliases.Items += [ "Example" ]'
```

#### [Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jcJt733eKx)

```json
{
  "CallerReference": "terraform-20210518124856158900000001",
  "Aliases": {
    "Quantity": 4,
    "Items": [
      "consumer-portal.mlb.effi.com.au",
      "*.mlb.effi.com.au",
      "coolvalue.mylocalbroker.com.au",
      "Example"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working, but how can I make the changes permanent? When I tried `jq '.Aliases.Quantity += 1 | .Aliases.Items += [ "Example" ]' $filename` it gives an output only but doesn't override the file though.

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565295/jq-to-replace-text-directly-on-file-like-sed-i). You'll need to do something like: `jq ... $filename > temp.tmp && mv temp.tmp $filename`

Comment: cool got it to work with `jq '.Aliases.Quantity += 1 | .Aliases.Items += [ "Example" ]' $filename > updatedcf.json`