# recursively delete all required keys in a JSON schema

Tags: json, shell, github-actions, jq, jsonschema

I have written a [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org) file for my Kubernetes Helm values files.

The schema defined some [required properties](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#section-6.5.3). I would like to publish modified schema without all required properties.

Background: With helm, it's possible to define a subset of the values files. IntelliJ highlights some error on such subset YAML files, since it misses some "required keys". Thats fine in this context, since the YAML files which holds a subset of the configuration will be merged with the base configuration.

Example JSON

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "blackbox": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "enabled": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                }
            },
            "required": ["enabled"]
        }
    },
    "required": ["blackbox"]
}
```

The schema itself is repeatable, the "required" key can also be found in a 9th or 10th nested level. That's why I need a solution which enables to do it recursively.

The step should be executed in GitHub Action, however any shell based solution is fine, too.

I was trying to play with jq, but I don't find the way here.

Example Output:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "blackbox": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "enabled": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. Do you want to remove the `"required"` field from the JSON, or the whole property / object associated to it?

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jq to replace text directly on file (like sed -i)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565295/jq-to-replace-text-directly-on-file-like-sed-i)

Comment: @KamilCuk I added an example output there.

Comment: @JeremyFiel I feel like no, because I have to replace a property in undefined nested levels. the question refer more to in-place edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recursively remove one key**

```bash
jq 'walk(if type == "object" then del(.required) else . end)'
# same as
jq 'del(..|.required?)'
```

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "blackbox": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "enabled": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Recursively remove multiple keys**

```bash
jq 'walk(if type == "object" then del(.type,.required) else . end)'
# same as
jq 'del(..|.type?,.required?)'
```

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "blackbox": {
      "properties": {
        "enabled": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all `"required"` properties at any level, the following expression should work:

```
del(..|.required?)
```

`?` is the [Optional Object Identifier-Index](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.7/#optional-object-identifier-index) which will suppress errors.

Sample output with your given input:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "blackbox": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "enabled": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```